# How i Protect my AAD access Token in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, api, azure-active-directory, jwt, data-protection

while using my Rest APIs inside the Flutter app i user Bearer Token to use resources the fiddler like tools fetch that whole requests and response with token. how i can protect the token actually token is more important than body, SO if any one have an idea how i protect that access token please let me know. Thanks in Advance:)

I tried to protect the body like i encrypt the body and decrypt at server side but i did not know i  protect token in headers. and the request which get the access token also not protected and pass credentials in Form body to get token the tool fetch the credentials also..i'm expecting how i protect that credentials and response (Token) which get from https://login.microsoftonline.com/DOMAIN_NAME/oauth2/token

Comment: `encrypt the body and decrypt at server side` ---> `https`?

Answer (score 0):

You protect the token by using HTTPS for all requests with your back-end.
The request (including headers) will be encrypted with TLS.
Is there a particular reason you would need an additional encryption layer?